# Zero initialization of POD

Tags: c++, visual-c++, initialization, compiler-bug

```
struct Line
{
    Bounds          bounds_;
    Vector          origin_;
    uint32_t        begin_; 
    uint32_t        end_;   
    dist            ascent_;
    dist            descent_;
};
```

which is used as follows:

```
Line line = {};
while (!parser.done()) {
    line = Line(); // zero-initialize
    ...
}
```

`Bounds` and `Vector` are non-POD classes, `dist` is a typedef for `int64_t`.

However, an optimized 32-bit release build of VC++11, seems to leave at least parts of `line` uninitialized inside the while loop. Why? According to [Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new/620402#620402), it should have zero-initialized it, right?

I log the values of the struct members to a file:

- after `Line line = {};`: non-POD types are default-initialized, the others are 0.
- after `line = Line();`: POD types still default initialized, others contain random values.

Comment: How are you observing this? By running the program normally and having tests *in the code*, or by looking at it in the debugger?

Comment: @chris: It is value-initialization, which I think, in this case is equivalent to zero-initialization.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: by writing the values to a log file. When running under the debugger, the memory location used for the variables happens to be zeroed out, so it's not visible.

Comment: @Nawaz, Oh, I must be confused. For some reason, I thought `Line()` would default-initialize it and those that were initialized would be initialized in the assigned to one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may have found a compiler bug, although I seem to remember that in C++98 the requirements for initialising POD-structs were not as clearly described.

According to C++03, the expression `Line()` must result in a *value-initialised* Line object, which in this case means that all members must be *zero-initialised* (as all members are scalars).

Note that eventual padding between the members does not have to be set to any definite value, so that can cause a false-positive when you look at the Line object as a blob of memory.

The work-around is to provide a default constructor for `Line` that explicitly initialises all members.

Comment: Yes, it really looks like a compiler bug. I'll update my question.

Comment: I've played around a bit with the code, and it looks like an optimizer bug of the 32-bit VC11 compiler. It simply forgets to zero-initialize the POD struct members. Compiling w/o optimization, or using the 64-bit compiler produces the assembly correct code.